# NoClassDefFoundError - using Factual Android driver to make basic database call

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I'm trying to begin using the Factual driver for Android in the app that I am building.  I've installed their driver by dropping the .jar file from [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/factual/factual-java-driver/1.5.2/) in my libs folder within my app.  I've essentially just taken the demo code from [here](https://github.com/Factual/factual-android-sdk-demo) and dropped it into my own activity, modifying as needed to initially get it working.

When I run the activity, I get a NoClassDefFoundError pointing to the line where I first instantiate Factual like so:

```
protected Factual factual = new Factual("KEY", "SECRET");
```

I had to make one change to the code so that it would be accepted by Eclipse.  That change was in the FactualRetrievalTask class below:

```
public class FactualRetrievalTask extends AsyncTask<Query, Integer, List<ReadResponse>> {
    @Override
    protected List<ReadResponse> doInBackground(Query... params) {
        List<ReadResponse> results = new ArrayList<ReadResponse>(); //changed from Lists.newArrayList();
        for (Query q : params) {
            results.add(factual.fetch("restaurants-us", q));
        }
        return results;
    }
```

The `List<ReadResponse> results = new ArrayList<ReadResponse>();` was `List<ReadResponse> results = Lists.newArrayList();`, but that was giving me an error that said "Lists could not be resolved".  Doing a little research, I determined I could change it to what it now is.

However, when I run, I get the `NoClassDefFoundError`, which points to `com.google.common.collect.Lists`.  I've got a feeling this change I made might be what's causing this, but I'm not sure how to proceed and resolve it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Pertinent Log below:

```
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.Lists
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at com.factual.driver.Factual.<init>(Factual.java:46)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at com.factual.driver.Factual.<init>(Factual.java:57)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at com.example.blobtag2.PlaceActivity.<init>(PlaceActivity.java:64)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1040)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1757)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1873)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1054)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4358)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
04-14 17:06:01.209: E/AndroidRuntime(11688):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to include [Google's guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.common.collect.Lists
```

Comment: turns out there were a bunch of dependencies missing, guava being one of them.  thanks!